# Href Route not working in Laravel

Tags: laravel

[image]

`%7B%7B%20route%20(` shows after I click a button. I am trying to pass an id together with the route.

This is my code

```
<?php
  foreach ($requests as $newRequests){
    echo '<td>' .$newRequests->company_name. '</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$newRequests->fname, $newRequests->lname.'</td>'; 
    echo '<td>'.$newRequests->job_position.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$newRequests->email.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$newRequests->contact_no.'</td>';


    if($newRequests->status == 'Pending'){
      echo "<td> <a href = '{{ route ('Admin.RequestsPage', $newRequests->id) }}' class='btn btn-primary btn-rounded'>Accept</a>
      <a class='btn btn-danger btn-rounded'>Decline</a> <input type = 'hidden' name='requestID value='.$newRequests->id.'> 
      </td>";
    } else if ($newRequests->status == 'Accepted'){
      echo "<td><span class='label label-table label-success'>Accepted</span></td>";
    } else{
      echo "<td><span class='label label-table label-danger'>Declined</span> 
      </td>";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: err, why using `echo` and blade template together?

Comment: @am05mhz because im displaying data from the db

Comment: you can use blade template to display data from db, or you can also use echo to display it, but you cannot mix them

Comment: @am05mhz ah okay, so is that the problem why it displays %7B%7B%20route%20( ?

Comment: yep, that is because the blade template is considered as regular string because of `echo`

Comment: @am05mhz thank you so much, it worked :D but how do you call the route in web.php? This is what I did `Route::get('/RequestsPage/{id}', 'AdminController@acceptRequest')->name('acceptRequest');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in href

```
   href="{{ route ('Admin.RequestsPage', ['id' => $newRequests->id]) }}"
```

and your route should be GET and use name of your route instead of this "Admin.RequestsPage"

Comment: `Route::get('/RequestsPage/{id}', 'AdminController@acceptRequest')->name('acceptRequest');` this is my route and its not working. but yes, it already got the id but its not updating the status of the request

Comment: Use name in href  :  href="{{ route ('acceptRequest', ['id' => $newRequests->id]) }}"

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH YOU SAVED ME!!

Comment: Im doing the same thing for declining requests but it gives me error that says not defined. :(

Comment: Please share url if your project is online OR share the screen shot of your screen

Comment: i alreeady posted

Comment: Can you share your controller, model and view code on any forum. Only related functions.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the documentation of laravel + blade template here
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data

put something like this in your controller:

```
return view('some-blade-template', ['url' => 'some/route']);
```

and a simple blade template like this:

```
<a href="{{ route($url) }}">Click me</a>
```